# After integrate cast framework app crashes when opening

Tags: android, crash, google-play-services, chromecast, google-cast

After integrate cast framework app crashes when opening.when google it everyone says device must update their google play services. How to prevent those errors.

Log says:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0
```

Comment: Did you try updating the Play Service version as suggested in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/issues/94) and [SO ticket](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37328990/5995040)?

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765632/runtimeexception-chromecast/47672089#47672089